# Authentication server for Google Apps

Tags: authentication

We are using Google Apps services in our startup for email and docs. However for some other purposes such as svn and bug tracker we have our local machines on which we have installed the required apps. All of them have their own separate credential sets.

Ideally I'd like to have one authentication (i.e. that of Google Apps) and authenticate on svn & trac etc. using them. Considering Google Apps does not support OpenID, what should be a good solution? Can I setup a server which uses a particular protocol and still nicely wraps around Google Apps authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Google Federated Login API](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) now, it provides OpenID services. Also, as [this guy has shown](http://openid-provider.appspot.com/), it's easy to use Google App Engine to create an OpenID provider of your own using Google IDs as the underlying credentials. HTH.

Comment: Google Federated Login API says:

"Note: OpenID authentication is currently supported for Google accounts only, not Google Apps (hosted) accounts."

Comment: Update: "Note: OpenID authentication now supports Google Apps (hosted) accounts"

Answer (score 0):

[OAuth](http://oauth.net/) may help, up to a point -- Google Apps' [gdata](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/) APIs do support it decently, see [here](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/oauth.html). Of course all this requires and concerns programming, not just system administration: but then I know for sure your question IS about programming, since it's on Stack Overflow -- if you meant to ask strictly about sysadm issues, you would *of course* be using serverfault.com, right?-)

Comment: Of course I have no problem hacking up together to get my work done but it'd be great if I built something on top of a concrete design. 

On the other hand it'd be great if I get an out-of-the box solution